# App suspended after i update it with a Banner from Ad Mob

Tags: android, admob

2 months ago I published an app on google play (as free) and now in an update, I added a Banner from Ad Mob to get some revenue.

My App got suspended and i received an e-mail from Google saying:

> "REASON FOR SUSPENSION: Violation of the intellectual property and
>   impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy".

I don't know where the problem is since i have a certified Ad Mob Account.

Here my code for the Ad Banner:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView=null;
        adView=(AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The AdView layout's Xml code is:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2561306222851578/9043392843">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Do you have put on the Google play developer console that your APP will contain ADS? Also did you tried it and does it works when you haven't published the app ?

Comment: You should put this question on Google Play support not on SO

Comment: @Skizo yes i tried the app before publishing  and it did work...However i didn't  mention that the update contains ADS maybe that's the problem i will let you know thanks =)

Comment: let me know if it works ;)

Comment: I tried adding ads with  another app and this times i checked the " My app contains ADS" box , 2 days have passed and my app is on Google Play seems that you were right .. thx again @Skizo

Comment: @NaZimBL You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look on this [`My app has been removed from Google Play`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981?hl=en) also on this [`google-play-store-copyright-issues-and-how-to-avoid-them`](https://viksaaskool.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/google-play-store-copyright-issues-and-how-to-avoid-them/).

As I mentioned on comments if you run your app before you upload it to `Google Play` and the ads are shown, I guess is problem of IP law and Google policies.

And also **MAYBE** it's because you put that in your `Google Play Developer console` that your app doesn't contains `ads` so you've to change it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons why an app can be suspended under the Developer Content Policy. The relevant information is here:

> **Impersonation or Deceptive Behavior:** Don't pretend to be someone else, and don't represent that your app is authorized by or produced by another company or organization if that is not the case. Products must provide accurate disclosure of their functionality and should perform as reasonably expected by the user.
>   Products or the ads they contain must not mimic functionality or warnings from the operating system or other apps.
>   Products must not contain false or misleading information or claims in any content, title, icon, description, or screenshots.
>   Developers must not divert users or provide links to any other site that mimics or passes itself off as another app or service.
>   Apps must not have names or icons that appear confusingly similar to existing products, or to apps supplied with the device (such as Camera, Gallery or Messaging).

Source: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Also, be sure that you have disclosed that your app contains Ads in the **Pricing & Distribution** section of the Google Play Developer Console.

[image: Google Play Contains Ads Declaration]